# foreach() return a null value

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I have another error anymore, when I try to display a result in my view, the result is NULL and I can't see the result of my query at models.

Here's my code list :

on the controller (home.php) :

```
$data['hasil5'] = $this->home_model->popular_list();
```

on the model (home_model.php) function popular_list() :

```
function popular_list($limit=2)
{   
    $this->db->select('news.*');
    $this->db->where('id',$this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->where('publish',1);
    $this->db->where('viewed >= ',5);
    $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    $query = $this->db->get('news');    
    return $query->result();
} //thanks to kumar_v
```

and on my view (home.php) as a part of "Popular news" :

```
<h2>Most Popular News :</h2>
<?php
foreach ($hasil5 as $data5):
?>  
  <div class="welcome clear"><img class="imgl" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/news/original/<?php echo $data5->image; ?>" alt="" height="119" width="125" />
    <div class="fl_right">
      <h2><?php echo anchor($data5->kategori.'/detail/'.$data5->id,$data5->title) ?></h2>
      <p><?php echo $data5->sinopsis; ?></p>
      </div>
  </div>

<?php
    endforeach;
?>
```

The results is NULL, can you correct it again? thanks..

Comment: can you also post the `var_dump($hasil5);`?

Comment: did you do `print_r($data["hasil5"]);` in controller?

Comment: @kumar_v : the result is Array ( ), what's that mean?

Comment: probably there is an error in your query which returns no results

Comment: your query returns empty result. `echo $this->db->last_query();` before `return $query->result();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
function popular_list($limit = 2) {
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                  ->where('id',$this->uri->segment(3))
                  ->where('publish',1)
                  ->where('viewed >= ',5)
                  ->order_by('id','DESC')
                  ->limit($limit)
                  ->get('news');

    print_r($query->result());
    return $query->result();
}
```

You can put the whole thing in `$query` variable. And also, you can improve your `$this->db->where()` by putting the params in an array.

Comment: @Vainglory07 - according to http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#chaining, this is not how to chain. remove the "->db". and i can't see how you solved the problem by chaining?

Comment: arty is right, I remove the "->db" and it's working, but the error occured in foreach, what's wrong with it sir?

Comment: i updated my code, try to print the `$query->result()`;

Comment: i think, you have to check @kumar_v suggestion, or just run [$query->num_rows()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) to check how many records you got back. or just print_r or var_dump the result of popular_list(). or comment all the wheres and try again

Comment: i also update my answer again :) because your code will work right if you will be going to use proper chaining.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your code to look like so:

```
<?php
  foreach ($data['hasil5'] as $data5):
?>
```

You were using the wrong variable in your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if the query will return any row is a good idea.

```
function popular_list($limit=2)
{   
    $result = null;
    $this->db->select('news.*');
    $this->db->where('id',$this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->where('publish',1);
    $this->db->where('viewed >= ',5);
    $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    $query = $this->db->get('news');    
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $result = $query->result();
    }
    return $result;
}
```